# Screen resolution too low on Dell e7240

Tags: dell, resolution, screen

I purchased a Dell Latitude e7240 with Ubuntu 12.04.

In system settings, the highest proposed resolution is 1366x768, which is well below my expectations.

I could not find any way to get an higher resolution. Anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest screen resolution of 1366 x 768 in *Systems Settings* -> *Displays* is correct. The [Dell Latitude E7240 Notebook](http://www.engadget.com/products/dell/latitude/-e7240/specs/) comes with a display with a resolution of 1366 x 768 pixels and a screen size of 12.5 inches. Even with the screen resolution set to 1366 x 768, it's sometimes going to be difficult to read text on the screen without being rather close to it.

Comment: "The E7240’s 12-inch touchscreen Gorilla Glass display is as sweetly responsive as its touchpad. Its native resolution of 1920x1080 is great for movies". http://www.pcworld.com/article/2150502/dell-latitude-e7240-ultrabook-review-small-fast-and-elegant.html

Comment: "http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/latitude-e7240-ultrabook/pd" ... indeed says 1366x768...   the review above seems to be mistaken